# CSS: search field results are at half width

Tags: html, css

I have issue with search dropdown results. Take a look at here: https://www.advokatami.bg/?s=firma&is_v=1 - click the magnifying glass in the top menu and try to search. The results are half width of the search form. How can i display it full width?

Comment: Please post the minimal code to reproduce your problem. - I haven't clicked the link, but from experience I suspect it being a problem with the wrong element using `position: relative;` or the results don't have a width.

Comment: Link not working @File_Submit

Comment: Link works fine here. Google Translate doesn't seem to work on it though.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/YqKOe this is css of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="aa-dropdown-menu tether-element tether-enabled tether-abutted tether-abutted-left tether-element-attached-top tether-element-attached-left tether-target-attached-bottom tether-target-attached-left aa-without-0 aa-without-1 aa-without-3 aa-with-2" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 99999; left: 0px; transform: translateX(1061px) translateY(218px) translateZ(0px); width: 280px; display: none;"><div class="aa-dataset-0"></div><div class="aa-dataset-1"></div><div class="aa-dataset-2"></div><div class="aa-dataset-3"></div>
<div class="autocomplete-footer">
    <div class="autocomplete-footer-branding">
                    <a href="#" class="algolia-powered-by-link" title="Algolia">
            <img class="algolia-logo" src="https://www.algolia.com/assets/algolia128x40.png" alt="Algolia">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

your span got an width=280px;

Comment: hmm, thank you! It appears this width is defined in js code 
var dropdownMinWidth = 280;
can i make it 100%? 
full js code at 127 row: https://codeshare.io/zKgSE

Comment: well, I think it will work if you change it to 500px

Comment: It will not be okay for mobile :(